# PHP if statement errmsg

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this if statment

```
if(!empty($URL) && ($safe===true)){
//lots of code
}
```

Is it possible to show different error messages depending on what condition failed?
For example if $URL is empty echo "URL empty";
and if     $safe===false echo "GTFO";

Comment: If neither are true, would you want to display both messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (empty($url))
    {
         echo "URL empty";
    }
    elseif ($safe === false)
    {
         echo "GTFO";
    }
    else
    {
        //lots of code
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your code

```
else if(empty($URL)
{
  echo "url empty";
}

else if($safe===false)
echo "Get Out"; // be polite  ;)
```

Comment: I had to make it `else if (!$safe === true)` to display. First answer so you get the score. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
} else {
  if($safe === false){
    die("GTFO");
  }
  if (empty($url)){
    echo "URL Empty.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you could make use of an `else if` statement.

```
if (!empty($URL) && ($safe===true)) {
    //lots of code
} else if (empty($URL)) {
    // report that url is empty
} else if ($safe === false) {
    // report that safe is false
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use an `else` statement to report that the if condition was false.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following solution. It will allow you to show multiple errors and set each condition only once (instead of having so many conditions and anti-conditions as other solutions proposed).

```
$errors = array();

if(empty($URL) {
    $errors[] = 'URL empty';
}

if($safe !== true) {
    $errors[] = 'GTFO';
}

if(empty($errors)) {
    //lots of code
} else {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $error_message) {
        echo '<li>' . $error_message . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```